# Display Text and various output for CMD prompt as well as menus and file explorer are behaving very slowly

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, cmd.exe

As stated in the title my computer is acting very odd, and I'm at a loss for where to even start figuring the issue.  Let me begin.

The CMD prompt will not display the text as I am typing it, a sure fire way to instantly see the text though is to resize the window, it's the strangest thing.  I could wait 10-15 seconds and it will eventually display, but resizing the window is much quicker.  While it doesn't display text, it is actively doing the commands its told.

Another odd issue is with bringing up the right-click menus, I will kind of see the outline shadow for the box but nothing will display for a long period of time, again if i click inside it the action will work immediately(i.e New Tab).  This isn't unique to my browser either this will happen with really any right-click menu or drop down menu.  The buttons will still work but I cant actually see them.

The last issue is that when this happens file explorer will also be very slow with displaying folders (working on it...).  Even renaming files or folders can be a pain because similar to the CMD it wont be displaying the text as I type it.  Re-sizing the window with the drag arrow will solve this quickly the same way it does for the CMD prompt.

I haven't been able to pinpoint what starts this behavior, it wont always happen at start up, some times my computer runs flawlessly, other days it behaves like that.  And its really only those 3 issues.  Everything else will display and run well whether its coding, testing, or just relaxing with a game.

Looking into my task manager nothing is out of the ordinary when this is going on, no massive amount of CPU is being used(some tabs in chrome and some text editing, maybe 4% usage), plenty of memory (maybe 30% usage), disk not even being used particularly 0% usage.

I have run memtest, and disk health checks and everything comes up good.  Specs are i7-4790k with 16gb of RAM.

This is starting to get very annoying as I get more work to be done, so any help or ideas with this would be greatly appreciated.  Like the problem is so odd I don't even know what to google.